# I/O-overhead of dm-encrypted device?

Tags: security, filesystems, performance, encryption

What would be the Read-/Write-overhead when using dm-crypt (LUKS) as full disk-encryption (including root partition) on a Linux-Desktop (Ubuntu)?
I plan to stack it like so: LUKS > LVM > ext4
The CPU in use on the system would be a Core2 Duo 2.1 GHz with 4GB of RAM.

- Would encryption of such a system create a great/noticeable overhead?
- Are there any recent benchmarks to be found on the net? What is your personal experience?
- Are there any settings I can make to improve performance?

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 12):

There is no I/O-overhead involved in dm-crypt - just CPU overhead ... ;)

On a Athlon 64 2.6 GHz dual core system for example I can copy from one dm-crypt disk to another with ~ 40 MB/sec (2.6.26 Kernel, Seagate 1.5 TB SATA disks).

For performance make sure that the for your architecture optimized aes module is loaded, e.g.

```
$ lsmod | grep aes
aes_x86_64             12416  6 
aes_generic            32552  1 aes_x86_64
```

Regarding data-safety, there is no need to disable the write-cache because of dm-crypt. Old versions didn't support write-barriers, but since 2010 (kernel 2.6.31 or so) dm-crypt [does support them](http://www.saout.de/pipermail/dm-crypt/2012-April/002441.html) (respectively force-unit-access - FUA).

Btw, one can argue that it does not really makes sense to encrypt the root-partition.

However, encrypting swap does make sense.

Comment: One might argue as well that messing around with hdparm when you don't know what you're doing (or only *think* you know) can damage your hard drives.

Comment: Encrypting the root partition makes sense if your threat model includes the possibility of an adversary gaining temporary physical access and booting in single user mode or from a USB drive and installing malware such as a key-logger or rootkit. For regular users, it also means not having to worry about forgetting to encrypt `/tmp` (if it's not mounted with `tmpfs) and any other directories that might leak private data.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan, this is perhaps effective against some adversaries. But to protect against the threat model you describe you also have to secure the bootloader (e.g. with a firmware that cryptographically checks the bootloader before executing it).

Comment: @maxschlepzig That very thought occured to me as I wrote the comment earlier but I didn't want to go overboard  with disclaimers and provisos in a small comment box.  The second reason is probably more important: I use FDE (on my 10 year old laptop) so I don't have to worry (as much) about credentials and private keys in `/etc` or some other sensitive data somehow being logged to `/var/` (upvoted, BTW).

Answer (score 0):

Ext4 may be a bad choice of filesystem if you are planning on performing LVM snapshots.  I would advise doing substantial disk performance checking before going live, experiementing with block sizes on both FS and LVM.  My experience was with Ext3, but the other articles I saw at the time implied that Ext4 had simular problems.

I solved it by using XFS as the filesystem.